# Female dog, spontaneous clear discharge

Tags: dogs, health

My fiancé and I have a 1 year old spayed female Rottweiler/Boxer mix, and she's been experiencing spontaneous clear fluid vaginal discharges. Sometimes it seems to be a slight mix of urine, but it's otherwise clear and odourless, with a slight viscosity (like very thin saliva). The volume ranges from droplets to pancake-sized puddles.

We've been taking her to pee when it happens, and she typically does, however it's never urgent once outside.

We've given her yogurt and cranberry extract, and that seemed to curb it for awhile, but not entirely; the effectiveness seems to have worn off.

We've yet to take her to the vet due to costs; she's in no pain and is otherwise a very healthy dog.

Any ideas? We'll be planning a vet visit in the near future, but I figured I'd try my luck here first.

Comment: I'd be really interested to know if the vet was able to shed any light on this for you?